# using multiple imports in content script, only one causes "Cannot use import statement outside a module" (browser extension, manifest v3, vite, .ts)

Tags: typescript, importerror, vite, browser-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I'm uncertain exactly how this started and apologize in advance if I am missing info. Happy to provide if you leave a comment.

I'm working on a chrome browser extension. The error only appears in the content script. I have slightly modified this typescript file: https://github.com/Arrow7000/dall-e-downloader/blob/master/src/content-script.ts . It works fine until I try to add `import {crc32} from 'crc';`. Importing it causes no issue, using it does. A simple test of `crc32('test').toString(16);` gives me the error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`.

When I check where the error occurred I see the first line of the compiled file:

`import { c as crc32 } from "../../../assets/crc32.aa06d663.js";`

If I look for other imports in the compiled file I see they are "actually" imported (they aren't still sitting as import statements). For instance, `saveAs` was imported and can be seen like `FileSaver_min.exports.saveAs(my, expected, params, are, indeed, here);`

If I check a local html page (terminology?? a webpage "hosted" by the extension. ex: `chrome-extension://asfdqwerty/index.html`) that uses the same crc import it works just fine. When I look at the compiled javascript I see a similar line `import { d as defineCrc, c as crc32 } from "../../../assets/crc32.aa06d663.js";` so my previous worry about "actually" importing it seems unnecessary.

In many similar QAs it's said to ensure `type="module"` is set. However this is a typescript file, there is no `<script>` tag. If I check the package.json file I see `"type": "module",` already set. And it works in another file already!

So, I have no idea what's going on. I just want to import this function.

Some project differences/notes:

- I'm using this boilerplate instead of a simple fork: https://github.com/NekitCorp/chrome-extension-svelte-typescript-boilerplate
- Code is compiled/bundled with Vite, something I haven't used before this project. I don't grok in the least.
- crc import works fine when in a .svelte file

**Thinking this has something to do with compilation/bundle process**

Answer (score 0):

**Workaround**

The background service_worker can be declared as a module:

```
"background": {
  "service_worker": "src/pages/background/index.js",
  "type": "module"
}
```

So, it's easy to pass messages from content_scripts to it. In my case I pass the data I want to find the checksum of.